# Linq To Sql update mdf file using clickonce

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq-to-sql, clickonce

I have a application  that use Linq2sql and have a database (mdf file). I using clickonce to release the application. I need to make changes in the database structure, How can i do this and update the mdf files using clickonce without losing the data at the files?

Comment: can you explain what you need to do exactly? do you want an update of the application to do not overwrite the mdf file you deployed on the first install? if so, can you have the logic to detect if the mdf file is in the old format in your application startup and only in the app startup you will update it the first time the new version has been started?

Answer (score 0):

If you place your mdf in the data directory then you can have access to that previous-version-mdf-file when the newly installed version is run for the first time, since old data files are accessible in a PRE directory.
So at that moment you can copy the data from the old mdf to the new mdf.

To give you the full picture, are data files are renewed when a new installation is done. Its up to you to copy any old data.

Link which explain the first run of a clickonce installation:
[How do I detect the first time a ClickOnce-deployed application has been run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811780/how-do-i-detect-the-first-time-a-clickonce-deployed-application-has-been-run)

Link which mentions the PRE data directory to access files from the previous version.
[clickonce - does writing/reading to the Data Directory required Admin rights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369025/clickonce-does-writing-reading-to-the-data-directory-required-admin-rights)