# Run external OneClick app from ASP.net Website

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, process

When attempting to run a .application OneClick deployment application from debug mode it runs with the following examples:

1. Use a `<a>` reference around the clickable image that launches the application

`<a href="\\server\SharedFolder\MainFolder\ExternalApp.application"</a>`

2. Other attempt was a start process

   ```
   Dim p As New Process()
   p.StartInfo.FileName = "\\server\SharedFolder\MainFolder\ExternalApp.application"
   p.Start()
   ```
3. VB.net Javascript call:

   VB.NET

   ```
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Pop", "LaunchApp();", True)
   ```

   JAVASCRIPT

   ```
   <script type = "text/javascript">
   function LaunchApp() {
       var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
       ws.Exec("\\server\SharedFolder\MainFolder\ExternalApp.application");
   }
   ```

Both options worked [aside option 3] when I was debugging. When I ran this outside the debugger it didn't work. Any suggestions as to why?

I read the following links but no luck:

[Run windows form app from asp.net page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245273/run-windows-form-app-from-asp-net-page)

Comment: FYI: user on pc can manually open the application from the path specified but not the ASP.net website I guess. Is there more permissions required to do so?

Comment: I have also attempted to run the `setup.exe` file as well. no luck outside debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using the `publish` build file that runs it in a generic html file. This is generated when you build the application. I ended up opening this with a windows popup and reformatted the design to match my website.

Simple workaround.